# What does "int*&&" do in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory-management

I'm coming from a C# background and trying to learn a little C++.
I came across the following lines:

```
int x[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int*&& y = x;
int* z = y;
```

I know what pointers and arrays are and have some small understanding on lvalue and rvalue references. However I can't wrap my head around what `int*&& y = x;` actually does.
It would read like it *creates a pointer to an rvalue reference*, is this correct? What would be the use case of something like that, e.g. what is going on in memory if we execute this?

Comment: In memory, probably nothing.

Comment: *'It creates a pointer to an rvalue reference'* -- No, it creates an rvalue reference to a pointer.

Comment: My humble advice, first learn about the KISS principle, then learn C++ from trusted sources (Stroustroup's *A tour of C++* may be a good start for you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int*&& y = x;` declares `y` to be a *rvalue reference to pointer to `int`* and initializes it with `x`. (Note that *pointer to reference* types (e.g. `int&&*`) do not exist in C++.)

Now the issue is that `x` is an *array of `int`*, not a *pointer to `int`*. So the reference can't bind directly to `x`. The types are not reference-compatible.

In such a situation (if the reference is either a rvalue reference or a `const` lvalue reference) an (unnamed) temporary object of the referenced type is created and the reference binds to that object instead. In this case an `int*` object is created and initialized with `x`, which by array-to-pointer decay means that the `int*` temporary object will be initialized to point to the first element of the array `x`.

Temporary objects normally live only until the end of the (full-)expression in which they are created, but in this case, because a reference is immediately bound to it, so-called *temporary lifetime extension* applies and the temporary `int*` object will live as long as the reference does (i.e. until the end of the reference's scope).

In other words it is (mostly) equivalent to

```
int* /*unnamed*/ = x;
int*&& y = /*unnamed*/;
```

where the comment `/*unnamed*/` is supposed to represent the non-existing name of the temporary object.

When a reference's name is used in an expression (and this is completely independent of whether or not it is a lvalue or rvalue reference), it behaves exactly the same as if the object to which the reference is bound would have been named instead (but with the type of the reference with reference-qualifiers stripped which may e.g. differ by a `const`).

In other words `int* z = y;` behaves equivalently to `int* z = /*unnamed*/;`. So `z` is intialized from the temporary `int*` object, which has a pointer value pointing to the first element of the `x` array. For scalar types like `int*` initialization is simply copying the value, so `z` will also be initialized to point to the first element of `x`.

The whole thing is needlessly convoluted. It is exactly equivalent to `int* z = x;`. Using rvalue references usually only really makes sense as function parameters and some constructs where type deduction occurs. The important difference between lvalue and rvalue references is that they affect overload resolution differently and that they may be initialized with different value categories. There is also one special case in type deduction where rvalue references behave differently (as so-called *forwarding references*). Aside from that there is no difference between the different kinds of references.

> what is going on in memory if we execute this?

That's mostly an implementation detail that shouldn't matter. You have an array that is stored somewhere depending on where you put these lines in your program. It is likely to be physically present somewhere in memory if the compiler doesn't figure it isn't needed. The reference `y`, the temporary `int*` which it points to and the `z` pointer may or may not actually be physically present in some memory, but the compiler is likely to just reduce all of them directly to the array. In particular, on the language level, references are not object and do not have storage (e.g. they don't have a memory size or location). If the compiler needs some memory to implement them (e.g. as a pointer), then that is purely an implementation detail of the compiler.

Comment: Could you add an example about the real world use case for `int*&&`? I'm just curious about it.

Comment: @LouisGo For `int*&&` directly there isn't really any use case that makes sense. More generally it doesn't really rvalue references don't really make sense with scalar types like pointers. It makes more sense if you have a generic function with e.g. `auto&&` and it just happens to be deduced to `int*&&`.